# Sending a transaction despite ContractLogicError

Tags: web3.py, python

I have my own private keys for an account and I'm using web3py to invoke a smart contract function. The way things are right now as per the docs, I first need to build the transaction, sign with my private keys and then send it as a raw transaction.

The problem is I can't build the transaction without it throwing a `ContractLogicError`. The function will be valid a few blocks down the line so I want to send it as soon as possible but even though the docs claim that `buildTransaction` doesn't actually send anything, it seems to validate the arguments with the current block for which it fails.

Is there a way for me to build the transaction without the smart contract validation, package it up and send it. This risks my contract failing on the chain and costing me gas fees, but it's a risk I'm willing to take.

Code looks something like this:

```
contract = [
    {"name":"send","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function","inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"gameId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"resourceId","type":"uint256"}]},
]

action = contract.functions.send(game_id, resource_id)
try:
    txn = action.buildTransaction({
        'chainId': CHAIN_ID,
        'maxFeePerGas': w3.toWei(max_fee, 'gwei'),
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.toWei(max_priority_fee, 'gwei'),
        'from': from_address,
        'nonce': nonce_manager[from_address],
    })
    signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, PRIVATE_KEY)
    txhash = Web3.toHex(w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction))
    receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txhash, timeout=60)
    nonce_manager[from_address] += 1
    return receipt, None
except Exception as e:
    return None, e
```

I get a contract specific exception when I run this: `INVALID RESOURCE_ID` and never even gets to `send_raw_transaction`. Removing it makes no difference. However if I put this in a while loop it eventually works after a few blocks.

Tested on latest `web3py` and Ubuntu 20.01 as well as Mac 12.1 both using Python 3.9.7

Comment: "Is there a way for me to build the transaction without the smart contract validation." Yes, there is, just add some source code to your answer so we can provide a useful response.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone As I mentioned in the question, I'm doing this exactly as mentioned in the docs. My source code is pretty much a copy paste of https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=contract%20function#sign-a-contract-transaction. The specific contract is irrelevant.

Comment: The `buildTransaction` method does not care about your node or the blockchain's current state, it cares about the ABI. `ContractLogicError` is fired if the transaction is sent and the contract's execution reverts. The example in the doc works, so that "pretty much" is where the problem lies. Maybe we can help if you share exactly what you are trying to do, differently than the base example.

Comment: "The buildTransaction method does not care about your node or the blockchain's current state" That is verifiably false. It throws a contract logic error in the build transaction step. I don't even have a `send_raw_transaction` step and it throws the error. There is no point in be posting the source code because it will look identical to the example. The only way to replicate it is to run my entire program because it keeps monitoring the blockchain and quickly attempts to react to a transaction. Since I can working off of data from pending transactions I am able to see what's about to happen.

Comment: I guess the issue here is I can't really replicate the error without sharing the full program (don't want to do that for a lot of reasons). I guess you'll have to take my at my word that it fails in that step. Not really sure what else I can do other than create some video of me running the program just to prove my question is based on a real premise.

Comment: Ok, don't worry about the video, if the code is exactly the same, you can just cut and paste in the question all the error lines you see in the console output. Add also information about your system operating system and python version (I tested for example on Ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.10, and it works fine).

Comment: Updated with code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to build the transaction without the smart
> contract validation, package it up and send it. This risks my contract
> failing on the chain and costing me gas fees, but it's a risk I'm
> willing to take.

If I understand correctly, you are almost there, just remember that what you call "smart contract validation" is just the gas estimation in **units of gas**. Basically a dry run on the provider side with no change whatsoever on the chain, simply returning the amount of gas used or an error if any. But that's an execution nonetheless.

The gas parameter (and others) will be automatically set if it is not already present.

Since  you define your tx with :

```
  txn = action.buildTransaction({
        'chainId': CHAIN_ID,
        'maxFeePerGas': w3.toWei(max_fee, 'gwei'),
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.toWei(max_priority_fee, 'gwei'),
        'from': from_address,
        'nonce': nonce_manager[from_address],
    })
```

There is no `gas` parameter and it will be set automatically through an internal call to [estimateGas](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html?highlight=estimate#web3.contract.ContractFunction.estimateGas), executing your smart contract function which fails... Simply setting a value for the `gas` parameter will solve your issue as no gas estimate will be required since a value will already be specified.

You can see a similar behavior with the following contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Example {

  function fail() public {
    require(false);
  }
}
```

And this web3 py code to build a transaction :

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:8545'))

abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "fail",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

contract = w3.eth.contract(address="0x8CdaF0CD259887258Bc13a92C0a6dA92698644C0", abi=abi)
action = contract.functions.fail()

# This will fail as it forces a gas estimation
txn = action.buildTransaction({'from': "0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57"})

# This will not
txn = action.buildTransaction({'from': "0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57", 'gas': 100})
```

The first call to `buildTransaction` fails, since the transaction is bound to fail with `require(false)`. You get `ContractLogicError`. The second call, specify a value for the `gas` parameter, no estimation is required and the tx can be sent. It will fail anyway in my example but not necessarily on yours. (comment out the first call to test the second one)

It might be better for you to poll the gas estimate to only send your tx when it has a chance to succeed, but that is your choice. You must also give enough gas for your function to run until completion.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted! For some reason I thought passing `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` was enough and that `gas` wasn't needed for EIP 1559. I guess this is one of those few times where automagical functions bite you because they try to intelligently fail. Would have preferred something like an explicit `gas: 'estimate' || <int>` but oh well. Thanks again!

Comment: Well you are in a special case, the api accommodates the majority of cases which are fine with a standard implicit estimate. Gas always needs to be specified, EIP-1559 changes how gas price are defined / distributed, but it does nothing on the amount of gas itself.